# I'm having trouble understanding importing in python3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, import

I've looked on many sites and many related questions, but following the solutions to those questions still didn't seem to help. I figured maybe I am missing something, so here goes.

My project is to create a DM's tool for managing table top role playing games. I need to be able to split my project into many different files in order to keep everything organized. (so far) I have only three files I'm trying to work with. I have my main file which I called `dmtool.py3`, I have a file for class definitions called `classdef.py3`, and I have a file for creating race objects called `races.py3`.

**1]** The first of my questions is regarding importing singular files. I've tried organizing the files in several different ways, so for this lets assume all of my three files are in the same directory.

If I want to import my class definitions from classdef.py3 into my main file dmtool.py3, how would I do that? `import classdef` and `import classdef.py3` do not seem to work properly saying their is no module with that name.

**2]** So I then made a module, and it seemed to work. I did this by creating a sub-directory called `defs` and putting the classdef.py3 and races.py3 files into it. I created the `__init__.py3` file, and put `import defs` in `dmtool.py3`. As a test I put `x = 1` at the very top of `races.py3` and put `print("X =", defs.x)` in `dmtool.py3`. I get an error saying that module doesn't have an attribute x.

So I guess my second question is if it is possible to just use variables from other files. Would I use something like `defs.x` or `defs.races.x` or `races.x` or maybe simply `x`? I can't seem to find the one that works. I need to figure this out because I will be using specific instances of a class that will be defined in the `races.py3` file.

**3]** My third question is a simple one that kind of spawned from the previous two. Now that `races.py3` and `classdef.py3` are in the same module, how do I make one access the other. `races.py3` has to use the classes defined in `classdef.py3`.

---

I would really appreciate any help. Like I said I tried looking up other questions related to importing, but their simple solutions seemed to come up with the same errors. I didn't post my specific files because other than what I mentioned, there is just very simple print lines or class definitions. Nothing that should affect the importing.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: afaik it should just be *.py ... I dont think you can name the extensions py3,py2.

Comment: Are you aware that modules are just implemented with single files? `defs.py` instead of a `defs` directory. Packages use folders, and you'd need to `import defs.races` to load the `races` module from the `defs` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, *do not use `.py3`* as a file extension.  Python doesn't recognize it.

Python 3's import system is actually quite simple.  `import foo` looks through `sys.path` for a package (directory) or module (`.py` file) named foo.

`sys.path` contains various standard directories where you would normally install libraries, as well as the Python standard library.  The first entry of `sys.path` is usually the directory in which the `__main__` script lives.  If you invoke Python as `python -m foo.bar`, the first entry will instead be the directory which contains the `foo` package.

Relative imports use a different syntax:

```
from . import foo
```

This means "import the `foo` module or package from the package which contains the current module."  It is discussed in detail in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), and can be useful if you don't want to specify the entire structure of your packages for every import.

Comment: `.py3` is not valid? Are you sure? I've used this for a project which worked perfectly. The files do run.

Comment: I ended up changing anyway.

I reorganized my files to all be in the same directory. Using `from . import races` came back with an error saying "Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import." So I tried replacing the . with the name of the file everything is in, and that had an error saying that that module didn't exist.

Comment: I removed the from section entirely. `import races` worked fine. Everything works, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Start python and type these commands:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

The path is the list of directories where python looks for libraries.  If your modules are not on the list, none are found.